# Is there any configuration or anything else we have to do to access another server from Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to access a third party api from my GAE server (JAVA), but I am not able to do so.

It is working fine in my local server but when I published the server to GAE, it just says "Crashed in GET!!"

Logs from the GAE server:

: 2016-05-13 10:45:55 [DEBUG] HttpConnection#open():692 Open connection to something.com:443

: 2016-05-13 10:45:55 [DEBUG] HttpConnection#releaseConnection():1174 enter HttpConnection.releaseConnection()

: 2016-05-13 10:45:55 [DEBUG] HttpConnection#releaseConnection():1178 Releasing connection back to connection manager.

: Crashed in GET!!

Any lead is appreciated.

Any firewall or restrictions from GAE which is not allowing me to access another server?

**Edit:**

after doing a little bit of debugging I was able to get the stacktrace

[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@1081859c Exception: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$FeatureNotEnabledException: The Socket API will be enabled for this application once billing has been enabled in the admin console.

Thanks for the help, added the bill details and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I use Python on appengine rather than Java, but there is nothing special required to access another public web server.

Is "Crashed in GET!!" typical of Java errors? It sounds odd to me - not terribly informative, and two exclamation marks. Could this be a user-generated string?